# How to add automatic dummy row using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have table with the following:

```
ID  TYPE    ProjectID   Date    Rev
1   A   1   30-1-2010   500
2   B   1   28-02-2011  580
2   B   2   30-04-2011  540
2   B   3   03-04-2019  440
```

Results:

```
ID  TYPE    ProjectID   Date    Rev
1   A   1   30-1-2010   500
1   A   2   01-01-2000  0
1   A   3   01-01-2000  0
2   B   1   28-02-2011  580
2   B   2   30-04-2011  540
2   B   3   03-04-2019  440
```

I want to write an SQL query in which, whenever there is Type “A”, two rows should automatically be inserted with project id 2 and 3 and with default Date and Rev data.

Currently, I am using `UNION` function to add this data manually, but I want to do it automatically.
I am not sure how to do this in SQL.

Comment: Do you want the query to return those two extra rows, or do you want the two rows to be inserted in the table itself?

Comment: I want the query to return those two extra rows

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select it.id, it.type, p.projectid,
       coalesce(t.date, '2000-01-01') as date, coalesce(t.rev, 0) as rev
from  (select distinct id, type from t) it cross join
      (select distinct projectid from t) p left join
      t
      on t.id = it.id and t.type = it.type and t.projectid = p.projectid;
```

This fills in the missing values, so all `id`/`type` combinations have all projects.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your quick response. i am getting error while trying this query as my sql query is very big query

Comment: Hi Gordon, i tried running in this sql server managament studio and getting wierd error.("id" is not a recognizable table hints option. if it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the changetable function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.)

Comment: I found that using command is not compatible with the server thats why error is coming

Comment: @RitikaKumari . . . Your question is tagged MySQL.  You should not be getting SQL Server errors using MySQL.